# Show that$\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{\cos (\pi \:n)}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}$ does NOT absolutely converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms

Show that$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\dfrac{\cos (\pi \:n)}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}$$ does **NOT** absolutely converge.

In order to do this, I must consider:

$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }|\dfrac{\cos (\pi \:n)}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}|$$ and want to show that it diverges. What test can I use? The divergence test would not work since the limit goes to $0$, and the comparison thereom seems like the best option, but I'm have a hard time finding a good comparison. Notice that the numerator will always be $1$.

I can say that

$$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\dfrac{\cos (\pi \:n)}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}} \geq \color{red}{\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}}$$

but then the series is still too hard to evaluate. How can I maybe clean up the denominator a bit, will still making the red series smaller (denominator must be bigger in red series)?

Comment: Did you mean to use $n$ in the summation?

Comment: Oh sorry yes Ill fix that

Comment: If so, $cos \pi n = (-1)^n$ may be helpful.

Comment: that may say alternating series test, but that test can only prove convergence, not divergence, if thats what your saying I should use

Comment: To prove that the series does not converge absolutely, integral test is a good one.

Comment: yes I could use that! thanks, simple u-sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that because of the $\pi$ in $\cos$'s argument and the fact that we're working over integers, we can say that $$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\dfrac{\cos (\pi \:n)}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}=\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}$$
Now, we want to look at the convergence of $$\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\left\vert\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}\right\vert=\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n\ln (n)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (n))}}$$
Notice that this is positive and decreasing (and continuous). So, use the integral test: $$\int_{3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x\ln (x)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (x))}}dx$$
Use the substitition $u=\ln(\ln(x))\implies du=\dfrac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx$ to get $$\int_{3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x\ln (x)\sqrt{\ln (\ln (x))}}dx=\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du=2\sqrt{\ln(\ln(x))}\bigg\vert_{3}^{\infty}\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that your last equation in your question is false.
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

Also, note that $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \lfrac1{n\ln(n)\ln\ln(n)}$ already diverges while $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \lfrac1{n\ln(n)\ln\ln(n)^{1+c}}$ converges for any real $c>0$, both by the integral test. You can easily extend this to any number of iterations of logarithms, and this shows you very roughly the boundary between convergence and divergence.

Finally, there is [another useful test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for slowly converging or diverging series when the terms are monotonically decreasing to zero, which is nothing more than combining the series terms into blocks of exponentially increasing size.

Specifically, given any decreasing non-negative sequence $f$, if we ignore the first term $f(1)$ and group the rest into blocks where the $n$-th block has size $2^{n-1}$ we get:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \le f(1) + f(2) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n f(2^n)$.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \ge f(1) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n-1} f(2^n) \ge \lfrac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n f(2^n)$.

If this is not strong enough we can repeat it to get:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \le f(1) + f(2) + 2f(2) + 4f(4) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n 2^{2^n} f(2^{2^n})$.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \ge \lfrac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n f(2^n) \ge \lfrac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n 2^{2^n} f(2^{2^n})$.

So in this case where $f(n) = \lfrac1{n\ln(n)\sqrt{\ln\ln(n)}}$ we get:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \ge \lfrac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{2^n} f(2^{2^n}) = \lfrac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lfrac{2^n 2^{2^n}}{2^{2^n} 2^n \sqrt{n}} = \lfrac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lfrac1{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$.